# OCaml parenthesis syntax error: parenthesis unmatched

Tags: ocaml

I wrote a function that sums all elements in a binary tree:

```
type 'a tree = Leaf of 'a | Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree;;

let rec sum_tree tree = match tree with
| Leaf l -> l
| a -> a
| Node(tree t1, a, tree t2) -> sum_tree t1 + sum_tree a + sum_tree t2;;
```

However, when I tried to compile this code, I met a syntax error:

```
let rec sum_tree tree = match tree with
| Leaf l -> l
| a -> a
| Node**(**tree **t1**, a, tree t2) -> sum_tree t1 + sum_tree a + sum_tree t2;;

Syntax error: ')' expected, the highlighted '(' might be unmatched
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: is **bold** not supported in a code block? I didn't know that... Sorry for the context. parenthesis and t1 with two stars are the highlighted parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a pattern like this:

```
Node(tree t1, a, tree t2)
```

But there is no pattern of the form `a b`, so `tree t1` makes no sense as a sub-pattern. It's not clear what you're trying to do with this pattern. At any rate that's what's causing the syntax error.

Most likely you just want to write this:

```
Node (t1, a, t2)
```

Now you have 3 sub-patterns that are going to match the three subparts of the node.